# Bulk update in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

My task is to update the status of inquiries coming from clients. Should I update the status of inquiries one by one row or use the following query (Bulk-Update)?

```
 update inquiries 
    set status = 'old' 
 where inq_id = 5 || inq_id = 6 || inq_id = 7 || ....
```

I am using [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) 9.1.

Comment: That's an invalid syntax. But other than that I have no idea what's the question.

Answer (score 2):

I *guess* this could be what you are looking for. For consecutive numbers:

```
UPDATE inquiries
SET    status = 'old'
WHERE  inq_id BETWEEN 5 AND 7;
```

Or, for any set of numbers:

```
UPDATE inquiries
SET    status = 'old'
WHERE  inq_id IN (5, 6, 7);
```